# Index Value goes to 5 million for nested for loop - C

Tags: c

I am programming a board game and I need to assign character values to a 2D array.  To do this, I am using a nested for loop with the i as the row index and j as the column index.  With a 4x4 dimension (n=4) The loop works fine until the second row.  Using the debugger on codelite, I've noticed that the value of j does not increase from 0 to 1 like it should, but it increases to 5,560,570, disrupting the loop.  I've also noticed that when using a dimension larger than 4, the program fails to display anything at all.  Is this a memory error?  I am stumped and have showed this to multiple other people as well.

```
int main(void){
int n;
char board[n][26];
printf("Enter the board dimension: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        if((i == (n/2)-1 && j == (n/2)-1) || (i == (n/2) && j == (n/2))){
            board[i][j] = 'W';
        }
        else if((i == (n/2) && j == (n/2)-1) || (i == (n/2)-1 && j == (n/2))){
            board[i][j] = 'B';
        }
        else{
            board[i][j] = 'U';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pay attention to your compiler warnings. If you're using GCC, always use `gcc -Wall -Werror`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that you are using `n` before you set it, in the declaration of `board`.  Because this is undefined behavior, absolutely anything is permitted to happen; in this case, that is disrupting the value of other variables.

To fix this, you should probably wait until after initializing `n` in `scanf` to declare `board`, like so:

```
 int main(void) {
     int n;
     printf("Enter the board dimension: ");
     scanf("%d", &n);
     char board[n][26];
     ...
  }
```

As has been pointed out in the comments, this still will cause problems if `n > 26`, and can be wasteful for `n != 26`.  Due to the way that arrays work in C, fixing that would probably require rethinking how the board is stored altogether.

Comment: You should show how to fix the problem, not just explain the error.

Comment: If n>26, there might be issue in accessing board[i][j], j might be out of boundary.